# Attribute error while compiling code

Tags: python, attributes

I was making a critter caretaker program in which i first created a class names Critter.
The first method i created is the constructor method in which i made three variables named "name", "hunger", "boredom".
I created many methods in this class.

I am not able to figure out what i have done wrong.

```
def Critter(object):

    def init(self,name,hunger = 0,boredom = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    def increase(self):
        self.hunger += 2
        self.boredom += 2
        return hunger,boredom

    def mood(self):
        unhappiness = self.hunger + self.boredom
        if 5 < unhappiness < 9:
            mood1 =  "unhappy."
        elif 9 < unhappiness < 14:
            mood1 = "Frustrated"
        elif unhappiness > 14:
            mood1 =  "Mad"
        return mood1

    def talk(self):
        print "Critter's name is ",self.name.upper()," and it is ",self.mood()," today."

    def eat(self,food = 4):
        self.hunger -= food
        if self.hunger < 0:
            self.hunger = 0
        self.increase()

    def play(self,play = 4):
        self.boredom -= play
        if self.boredom < 0:
            self.boredom = 0
        self.increase()

def main():
    choice = None
    name = raw_input("Please enter the name of the critter = ")
    crit1 = Critter(name)
    while choice != 0:

        print """

        0 - EXIT
        1 - SEE YOUR CRITTER'S MOOD
        2 - FEED YOUR CRITTER
        3 - PLAY WITH YOUR CRITTER

        """
        choice = int(raw_input("Enter your choice = "))
        if choice == 1:
            crit1.talk()

        elif choice == 2:
            crit1.eat()

        elif choice == 3:
            crit1.play()

    if choice == 0:
        print "Good bye ......"

main()


THIS IS THE CODE ,when i run it shows an error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sahib navlani\Desktop\gfh.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\sahib navlani\Desktop\gfh.py", line 54, in main
    crit1.talk()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'talk'
```

Comment: You are accessing `hunger` and `boredom` as local variables, not instance attributes, in `increase`.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two problems.

One is you need to use

```
class Critter(object):
```

not

```
def Critter(object):
```

The second is the

```
    def init(self, name, hunger=0, boredom=0):
```

should be

```
    def __init__(self, name, hunger=0, boredom=0):
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .I know that a did a nooby mistake,but thanks for answering

Comment: Sure — you're welcome. Your code was declaring a function that returned nothing (`None`) and was being called instead of class `__init__()` method (which why you hadn't encountered the second error yet). BTW you misspelled Medi-Caps on your profile page.